# Filter by the value of a cloumn generated by a subquery (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a query like this:

```
 select name,(select count(*) from relation r where s.id_student = r.id_student) courses
 from student s;

  +-----------+--------+
  | name    | student |
  +-----------+--------+
  | Jorge     |      4 |
  | Guillermo |      2 |
  | Hector    |      2 |
  | Diana     |      2 |
  | Diego     |      4 |
  | Mariano   |      2 |
  | Fernanda  |      1 |
  | Ricardo   |      2 |
  | Issac     |      2 |
  | Jaime     |      0 |
  +-----------+--------+
  10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I want to show only those students that have more than 2 courses. If I make a "where courses > 2" gives me an error because the column is not in the table students. So, how do I filter to get the desired result?

NOTE: I know I can solve this issue using JOINS instead of a subquery, but it drives me crazy not to find an aswer for the subquery solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` clause to filter the result set provided by your subquer

```
select name,
(select count(*) from relation r where s.id_student = r.id_student) courses
 from student s
HAVING courses >2
;
```

Comment: Wow, so easy and I was so confused trying to solve the issue, thanx a lot.